# Where is a non-empty open set connected iff path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected, locally-connected

I would to know how can the following claim can be generalized:

> **Theorem.** A nonempty open set in the plane is connected if and only
>   if any two of its points can be joined by a polygon which lies in the set.

An example of generalisation would be plane$=\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ into metric space (or some special type of metric space).

"joined by polygon", I assume, could be generalised to "path-connected" (meaning a continuous map $[0,1]\to X$).

Comment: Path connected implies connected as all that can be show.

Comment: @WilliamElliot If I understand correctly you are saying that "Every path-connected space is connected" (in any topological space), thus any path-connected set is connected. Therefore the only interesting part of the claim in the Q is the other direction.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56741/connected-implies-path-polygonally-connected) and [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011444/path-conectedness-of-open-balls-implies-path-connectedness).

Comment: A classic fact is that in a locally path-connected space, an open subset of $X$ is path-connected iff it is connected. This generalises the $\Bbb R^n$ and other locally convex spaces situation, where we can replace path-connectedness even by polygonally connected (which is handy for integrals in complex analysis e.g.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Exersice 6.3.10 from “General Topology” by Ryszard Engelking (2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989), a topological space $X$ is *locally pathwise connected* if for every $x\in  X$ and any neighbourhood $U$ of the point $x$ there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that for any $y\in V$ there exists a continuous mapping $f: [0,1]\to U$ satisfying $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. In the exercise is proposed the following. Verify that every locally pathwise connected space is locally connected and give an example of a locally connected subspace of the plane which is not locally pathwise connected (cf. Problem 6.3.11). Show that every connected and locally pathwise connected space [and so every open connected subspace of a locally pathwise connected space AR.] is pathwise connected.